# Adding multiple attachments to automated email using bmail/mpack on Windows

Tags: email, automation, scheduled-tasks, attachment, email-attachments

I use Bmail and mpack to automate the sending of email messages containing reports, error messages etc, from a virtual machine running Win XP.

An explanation of how this is done (and where I sourced the solution in the first place) [can be found here](http://retired.beyondlogic.org/solutions/cmdlinemail/cmdlinemail.htm).

For single file attachments, this is perfect. However I can't find a way to make mpack attach two (or more) files in a single email. Of course, I can send two emails to the same recipient, one after another, but I'd like to do it all in one if I can. It's better for the user if there's only one email.

Any suggestions how I can make this work with mpack/bmail, or are there alternative solutions I haven't considered?